# How to make browsers to support self-closed xhtml tags?

Tags: qt, xslt, xhtml

Using xslt to generate web-content (QXmlQuery), the resulting xhtml page has self-closed tags, which I am unable to make browsers to understand.

The problem relates with major browsers keeping parsing the self-closed tag as if it was HTML5, thus, including following content inside the self-closed tag.

Example:

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></xsl:attribute></a>
```

Will generate content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
...
<a name="Intro"/>
Some content
```

Which is then interpreted in the browser as:

```
<a name="Intro">Some content</a>
```

A trivial, but not elegant solution is to add a comment:

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:comment/></a>
```

I would like to understand the problem:

Is xhtml deprecated? If this is the case, then xslt for web generation is deprecated too?
If not deprecated, how to enable proper parsing of xhtml for modern browsers? (with proper, I mean with support for self-closed tags).

I tried several DOCTYPEs, and looked about the possible xslt deprecation without results. But I have to admit that I have been out of web development for a while, forgive me if this is a trivial question.

### Full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span/>
            Dummy content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which can be seen with "Dummy content" wrongly inside `span`

[image]

Comment: What is the media-type (content type) of the document as delivered from the HTTP server?

Comment: There is no server at all: xslt is used to convert content which is injected in a Chromium viewer (QWebEngineView). I can download the converted content and open that local file in a normal browser.

Comment: So is it a problem with "major browsers" as stated in the question. or with Chromium viewer as stated in your comment? And where is the XSLT running?

Comment: I tried with Chrome, Firefox and that embedded Chromium, with equal results. I can also try on other browsers, but I think it is not required.
XSLT is running in the QXmlQuery object.

Comment: The question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645642/serving-xhtml-and-self-closing-tags?rq=1 suggests that it's all about serving the content with the right media type, and I have no idea what happens if there's no HTTP header to base that on. But media type detection is almost certainly at the heart of the problem.

Comment: I will investigate the case

Comment: In the absence of a server, browsers treat local files depending on the file extension, so to treat the file as XHTML, the file needs to have an extension of `.xhtml`.  I don't know what QWebEngineView will do though. XHTML is not deprecated, but the name is, and XHTML 1.1 is obsolete. It's now called the XML syntax of HTML5. The content type/file extension rules remain the same though.

Comment: For QWebEngineView, maybe use [setContent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setContent) and provide the mimeType parameter as `application/xhtml+xml`

Comment: Changing the extension or setting the mime type with `setContent` effectively switch the browser to accept self-closed tags. It currently add plenty of "xmlns=''" everywhere, which break the css, but that is another topic.

Comment: There seems to be not even a single xhtml5 validator working outside there?

Comment: Or without QWebEngineView, put an `<xsl:output>` element in the stylesheet. See [MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Element/output).